# Show that if $f$ is complex differentiable and in some region $U$ it is $f'=0$, then $f$ is constant

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have to show show that if $f$ is complex differentiable and in some region $U$ it is $f'=0$, then $f$ is constant. How can one prove it?

Comment: I suppose in your book/course, "region" denotes a connected open set? Otherwise it's false, just in case that isn't clear. What methods have you available? You can deduce it from the real-variable result that a differentiable function with derivative $\equiv 0$ is locally constant. You can derive it from the power series expansion of holomorphic functions, from the identity theorem, ...

Comment: yes, connected one, i didnt have yet identity theorem. power series are available. how can I deduce it from real case?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, say in Remmert "region" stands for open connected subset of the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

You must assume that the region is connected, obviously.

When $U$ is open and connected, it is path connected.

Let $a,b\in U$. There is a path 
$$
c:[0,1]\to U
\\
c(0) = a\\
c(1) = b
$$where $c$ is $C^1$. Then the application $f\circ c$ is $C^1$ as well, has a derivative of $0$ and so is constant. Hence $f(a) = f\circ c(0) = f\circ c(1) = f(b)$.

Comment: Thanks, $C^1$ in complex sense?

Comment: no, this is a real variable!

Comment: but $f$ is a complex function...

Comment: $f\circ c$ is a complex **valued** function of a real **variable**.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in U$ and $V=\{z\in U / f(z) =f(a)\}$. Show that $V$ is open and closed in $U$.

Let $b $ in $ V$ hence $ b$ in $ U$. There is $ r>0$ st the ball $B(b,r)$ is in $U$.Fix $z$ in this ball. The map $g(t)=f(tb+(1-t)z)$ is dif and $g'=0$ then $g(0)=g(1)$. This show the opnes.

$V$ is closed in $U$ because $f$ is continuous.